# php not loaded but the code exist in view source page

Tags: php, apache, centos, cpanel, whm

i was setup my server, unfortunately the php page not loaded in the browser. Looking at the view source pages, i see my php codes. I using centos and install cpanel.
What usually reason for the problem?

Comment: PHP is not running on your server.

Comment: or not properly configured, or you're doing something silly like putting your php code into a .html file and didn't associate .html with the php interpreter.

Comment: yes, someone in the street say to LoadModule in httpd.conf. But my php modules (libphp5.so) is not exists in the location.

Comment: did you confirm if the modules actually did load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means PHP is not running. 
Have you tried reaching localhost in your browser? Generally you should see the PHP index file, which tells you if the server works or not.

A few possibilities :

- Is your file in the proper root folder? Is is accessed via localhost (not file system!)
- is your file in .php (ex. NOT .html)?
- Are you using full `<?php ?>` tags? Some server configs won't recognise `<? ?>`